# C# Textbox properties do not update

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, textbox

I have a simple form with a text box, a command button and a couple of timers. The only purpose of the form is to advise the user what is happening. The program executes all the code as required **EXCEPT for the textbox changes**.  I know the code to implement the textbox changes is executed because the form and the command button properties change as required.

I have added this.refresh and this.textbox1.refresh to no avail.

I am new to C# and most of the time I do not have Visual Studios available, so your assistance would be most appreciated.  I have read other posts on this topic and probably the answer has already been given, but I have not understood the solution.

The simplified code is given below:

```
    //PROGRAM.CS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication1;

namespace PostBinaryFile
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1(args));
            }
    }
}

//FORM1.CS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string sUrl;
        string sFileName;
        string sCorNo;
        public Form1(string[] args)
        {
            sUrl = args[0];
            sFileName = args[1];
            sCorNo = args[2];
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Start();
        }
        public void PostCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string sToken;
            string sPath;
            const string boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L";
            try
            {
//Do all general code work here.
//Alter form to show successful post to web
                this.button1.Visible = true;
                this.button1.Enabled = true;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(189,194,241);
                this.textBox1.Text =  sCorNo + " Outlook file saved to FuseDMS.";  // this code is executed but is not reflected on the Form
                this.textBox1.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(189,194,241);  // this code is executed but is not reflected on the Form
          }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            PostCode();
        }
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            this.textBox1.Text = "Saving Message " + sCorNo + ".";
        }
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to be calling `InitializeComponent()` on every timer tick? Are you aware that this resets all your properties?

Comment: If I got your problem correctly the text in your text box doesn't refresh through this code `this.textBox1.Text = "Saving Message " + sCorNo + ".";` when timer2's tick event fires. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidG pointed out, you should not call `InitializeComponent()` periodically or even more then once, do it as the first thing in the constructor.

This is because any controls and properties that you add/set from the designer are created and initialized in this method.

Another thing to point out is `Timer.Enabled = true` and `Timer.Start()` effectively do the same thing

From: [System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Calling the Start method is the same as setting Enabled to true. Likewise, calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false.

Comment: Removed the InitializeComponent() from "public void PostCode()".  Fixed the problem.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both timers namely `timer1` and `timer2` fire asynchronously and run on separate threads which are completely independent of each other. Even if timer2's tick event would be setting/refreshing the text appropriately through below code:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "Saving Message " + sCorNo + ".";
```

you can never say with guarantee that it will happen only after timer1's tick event has completed the execution of its callback method. In all likelyhood your above code is setting the text property of a dangling text box instance as your `InitializeComponent` function (being called from timer1's tick event) must be reinstantiating a new instance of all the form controls.

Your call to `InitializeComponent` function in `PostCode` method which gets called from tick event of timer1's tick event isn't right as it resets all the instances of form controls to new ones. It should be called only once in the constructor of the form. Just remove that piece of code and you should be good. Your `PostCode` function should actually look like this after you get rid of that piece of code:

```
public void PostCode()
        {
            string sToken;
            string sPath;
            const string boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L";
            try
            {
//Do all general code work here.
//Alter form to show successful post to web
                this.button1.Visible = true;
                this.button1.Enabled = true;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(189,194,241);
                this.textBox1.Text =  sCorNo + " Outlook file saved to FuseDMS.";  // this code is executed but is not reflected on the Form
                this.textBox1.BackColor= System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(189,194,241);  // this code is executed but is not reflected on the Form
          }
```